# What magics does Flink use in distinct()? How are surrogate keys generated?

Tags: apache-flink

Regarding generating surrogate key, the first step is to get the distinct and then build an incremental key for each tuple.

So I use Java Set to get the distinct elements and it's out of heap space.
Then, I use Flink's distinct() and it totally works.

Could I ask what make this difference?

Another related question is, can Flink generate surrogate key in mapper?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flink executes a `distinct()` internally as a `GroupBy` followed by a `ReduceGroup` operator, where the reduce operator returns the first element of the group only.

The `GroupBy` is done by sorting the data. Sorting is done on a binary data representation, if possible in-memory, but might spill to disk if not enough memory is available. This [blog post](http://flink.apache.org/news/2015/05/11/Juggling-with-Bits-and-Bytes.html) gives some insight about that. `GroupBy` and `Sort` are memory-safe in Flink and will not fail with an `OutOfMemoryError`.

You can also do a distinct on a custom key, by using `DataSet.distinct(KeySelector ks)`. The key selector is basically a `MapFunction` that generates a custom key.